# How can I make a link properly in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make the link to Amazon associate's.

If I put keyword between `<a type=amzn>` and `</a>` it automatically makes link to the amazon search result page with keyword.

I'm trying to make the button that works that way.
How can I archive that?

It should be something like this.

**view**

```
<%= link_to "Buy", "<a type=amzn >" + @book.title + "</a>", :class => 'btn' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
<%= link_to @book.title, "", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :type => 'amzn' %>
```

Comment: Thanks but it takes me to http://example.com/books/Harry_Potter?class=btn&type=amzn

Comment: Thanks I just noticed it won't be a button, also search query will be "Buy Harry Potter" not just "Harry Potter"

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I do use twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. It still won't become a button. It's just label.

Comment: This is generated html `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias=blended&amp;field-keywords=HarryPotter%BAX&amp;tag=mike1987&amp;link_code=wql&amp;_encoding=UTF-8">HarryPotter</a>`

Comment: I think it's replacing the tag. Not sure what to do from here. :(

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possible way not to use helper??

Comment: Even if you didn't use the helper and put in the class manually, whatever script you're using to generate the Amazon link is replacing the entire 'a' tag, so unless you can modify that script, I'm not sure  how you'll be able to retain the class.

Comment: After the Amazon links are created you could run your own script to add the button classes back to the links. That should be easy to do and won't require modifying any 3rd party code.

Comment: @foo, sure. Are you using jQuery? Please post whatever JavaScript you are currently using for the Amazon links...as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
<%= link_to @book.title, :class => "btn" do %>
  and
<% end %>
```

Where `and` is whatever you want the text on the link to be.

I am not 100% sure if I am understanding what you are looking for, correctly - but if I am...then this should work.